# Remove specific word and space

Tags: text-processing, sed

When I run the following command to remove the following domain, then it removes the domain and shows a blank line. How can I remove that line as well ?

I have tried different methods of sed and awk but did not get any solution.

`sed -e 's/\networkconfig.net\>//g' list`

```
cdn.sdo.org
toqeer.softglaxy.com

blog.lifei.com
blogs.lifei.com
whyyouare.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `d` command:

```
sed /networkconfig.net/d list
```

will output the contents of `list`, except any line containing `networkconfig.net`.